# I have entered input but clicking on submit is again asking for input when running an automation through blue prism for browser based application

Tags: blueprism

I am working on one web application. I am entering input in the text box, but when I click on Submit, I am again prompted to enter the input. How can I focus on the textbox or do a left click on the textbox before entering the text? I am trying to do this through blue prism.

Comment: Have you observed the automation in action? Is the value written to the input field, or does it remain blank before you submit the form? Is the site you're attempting to automate based on any framework (React, AngularJS, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a web page can have Javascript code that detects keyboard events, and if it didn't detect any, it might think there's no input. Assuming that you have entered the input using a write stage before, you might need to use the Global Send Keys or Global Send Key Event actions instead (they should be available in the Navigate stage, and you use them on the TOP level element of the application model). Please note that prerequisites:
-The browser window will have to be active (Activate Application on the Win32 browser window element)
-The textbox should also be active (Click Centre on the textbox element)